# Servicestack POSTing DateTime issue

Tags: c#, rest, datetime, servicestack, dto

Weirdly, this works locally but when it's deployed to an Azure website it doesn't

The `POST` variables that fail on Azure are:

```
name=Test&venue=1&fromDate=26%2F06%2F14&toDate=01%2F07%2F14&eventType=1
```

If I POST the following it works:

```
name=Test&venue=1&eventType=1
```

So it must be something to do with the date format.

The data type on the request is a `DateTime`, if I set this to string it works - I can then call `request.ConvertTo<Model>` and everything is passed over as expected. I just don't want to set the fromDate and toDate to be strings on the request.

Does anyone know why this would fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a globalization issue. The Azure servers will be using `en-US` culture that expects the dates in `mm/dd/yy` format for parsing.

But you are using UK date format `dd/mm/yy`, so the culture is `en-GB`. Your development machine will be set to use the `en-GB` locale already, hence no problems when testing locally.

You can specify the culture in your `web.config`:

```xml
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <globalization uiCulture="en-GB" culture="en-GB" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Or you can do so at runtime in `global.asax`:

```cs
public void PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB");
}
```

Or you could modify how ServiceStack.Text deserializes `DateTime`, but I wouldn't recommend that approach. In the `AppHost` `Configure` method:

```cs
JsConfig<DateTime>.DeSerializeFn = date => DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Hope that helps.